# Environmental specific imports

Tags: reactjs, webpack, es6-modules

Hey guys my company has the task that we are rebuilding our entire app and website in react from a 10 year old mvc thing...

They want to export some of the components from the new site into the existing site while we rebuild. What I was looking for is whether there is a webpage plugin or loader that acted like metro so I could say import * from 'package' and if I wanted to slightly customise it I could have 'package.old.ts' and 'package.ts' if package.old exists then it will import that otherwise it will do package?

Answer (score 0):

### Webpack's built in resolve.extensions

If by package you mean a module (a ts/tsx file in your project) you can solve this by using Webpack's `resolve.extensions` [configuration option](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolve-extensions).

Webpack will always evaluate this array left to right, the first one found wins. Therefore if you define the array as: `['.old.ts', '.ts', /*others*/]` it will try to match *package.old.ts* before *package.ts*

**Working example:**

package.old.ts:

```
export const message = "Hello old";
```

package.ts:

```
export const message = "Hello new";
```

index.ts:

```
import {message} from './package';
console.log(message);
```

This will output

> Hello old.

If you remove or rename package.old.ts it outputs new. **If you want to change the priority** all you have to do is reorder the array in your *webpack.config.js*